# проблемы с EventListener

Tags: javascript, angular5

Работает только если открыто несколько окон. Как сделать чтобы работало, если открыто одно окно?

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { AppStorageService } from './_services/app-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(
    private eventManager: EventManager
  ){
     window.onstorage = (e) => console.log(e);
  }

  onTest(){
    this.state = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: в документации MDN четко написано `The storage event fires when a storage area has been changed in the context of another document.`

Comment: @overthesanity и как же о ализовать если у меня одна вкладка? Принудительно открыть фрейм?

Comment: нет, зависит от задачи которую вы решаете

Comment: @overthesanity Задача такова...при нажатии кнопки "войти" в сессию пишется токен, эмэйл и имя пользователя. Я хочу отобразить имя пользователя. Т е если человек выйдет, то нужно ловить снова изменение в сессии.

Comment: для этого используются сервисы или redux, но точно не слушание событие стореджей браузера

Comment: @overthesanity а конкретнее можете написать или, что было бы лучше, дать почитать как использовать например сервисы для отслеживания изменения переменной

Comment: https://www.technouz.com/4776/custom-angular-application-state-service-with-behavioursubject/